# Server can not find class in .ear

Tags: java, maven-2, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, ear

I have some problems with my .ear file. The structure of the file is:

```
app.ear
|-xxx.jar
 -yyy.jar
 -zzz.jar
 -ektorp.jar
 -app-ejb.jar
 -app-web.war
  |-WEB-INF
    |-lib
      |-xxx.jar
      |-yyy.jar
      |-zzz.jar
      |-ektorp.jar
```

When I try to deploy my application, I get ClassNotFoundException, with class wihch is in ektorp.jar. This file is used by ejb module.

I also don't know why these jars are doubled? In ear and in war module are the same .jar files.

Ear is built by maven2.

Comment: Could you also post you application.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I try to deploy my application, I get ClassNotFoundException, with class which is in ektorp.jar. This file is used by ejb module.

Does the EJB-JAR reference `ektorp.jar` in the `Class-Path:` entry in the manifest (see [Packaging EJB 3 Applications](http://www.developer.com/java/ejb/article.php/10931_3670496_2/Packaging-EJB-3-Applications.htm) for more background on this)? The FAQ explains [how you can configure the plugin to generate a `Class-Path:` entry in the manifest](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/faq.html#How_can_I_specify_a_Class-Path:_entry_in_the_manifest_of_an_EJB_jar):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
           </manifest>
         </archive>
       </configuration>
        ...
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
 </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Just in case, do you know that you can package EJBs in a .war with Java EE 6 (the difference is that all classes are loaded with the same classloader when using the .war packaging)? If you don't have strong modularization requirements, the .war packaging is simpler.